# why i obtain integer(0) if i have the value at the vector?

Tags: r, function, indexing, position, sequence

i am creating a vector with a numerical sequence in R:

bins<-seq(-4,6,0.01)

i get 1001 values from -4.00 to 6.00 (-4.00,-3.99,-3.98, etc) but when i use the function which() certain values return integer(0) in spite of the value is in the vector:

```
> which(bins==4.04)
integer(0)
> which(bins==4.03)
integer(0)
> which(bins==4.02)
[1] 803
> which(bins==4.01)
[1] 802
> which(bins==4.00)
[1] 801
```

i verified the values and they are the same type: double

Comment: This is a common problem that you always need to keep in mind when testing equality between floating point numbers. See the linked duplicate for details.